# Import JS and CSS files into the JSP file, and the browser console prompts 404

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, intellij-idea

I imported JS and CSS files in the head part of the JSP file. However, some JS and CSS files prompt 404 errors. My < head > section is as follows:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../editor/examples/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../editor/css/editormd.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../editor/lib/codemirror/codemirror.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../editor/lib/codemirror/addon/dialog/dialog.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../editor/lib/codemirror/addon/search/matchesonscrollbar.css">
    <script id="-lib-codemirror-codemirror-min" type="text/javascript" src="../editor/lib/codemirror/codemirror.min.js"></script>
    <script id="-lib-codemirror-modes-min" type="text/javascript" src="../editor/lib/codemirror/modes.min.js"></script>
    <script id="-lib-codemirror-addons-min" type="text/javascript" src="../editor/lib/codemirror/addons.min.js"></script>
    <script id="-lib-marked-min" type="text/javascript" src="../editor/lib/marked.min.js"></script>
    <script id="-lib-prettify-min" type="text/javascript" src="../editor/lib/prettify.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://pandao.github.io/editor.md/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

The prompt in the browser console is as follows

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (codemirror.min.js, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (codemirror.min.css, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (dialog.css, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (matchesonscrollbar.css, line 0)
```

It can be seen that the "/ Editor" directory is missing in the prompted error
But when I modify other JS and CSS paths, the same error will be prompted

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../editor/examples/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/editormd.css"> <!--delete editor/-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../editor/lib/codemirror/codemirror.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../editor/lib/codemirror/addon/dialog/dialog.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../editor/lib/codemirror/addon/search/matchesonscrollbar.css">
    <script id="-lib-codemirror-codemirror-min" type="text/javascript" src="../editor/lib/codemirror/codemirror.min.js"></script>
    <script id="-lib-codemirror-modes-min" type="text/javascript" src="../lib/codemirror/modes.min.js"></script> <!--delete editor/-->
    <script id="-lib-codemirror-addons-min" type="text/javascript" src="../editor/lib/codemirror/addons.min.js"></script>
    <script id="-lib-marked-min" type="text/javascript" src="../editor/lib/marked.min.js"></script>
    <script id="-lib-prettify-min" type="text/javascript" src="../editor/lib/prettify.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://pandao.github.io/editor.md/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (modes.min.js, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (editormd.css, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (codemirror.min.css, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (dialog.css, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (codemirror.min.js, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (matchesonscrollbar.css, line 0)
```

These files are both in the "editor" directory. I have also tried to restart idea. Clearing the browser cache and restarting the computer have no effect. Hope to get an answer。

My project structure as fellow（I'm a beginner and can't send pictures）：

project

    .idea

    out

    src

    target

    web

      --editor

        ---css

        ---examples

        ---lib

        ...

      --jsp

        ---edit.jsp (error file)

        ...

Comment: Try defining resources related to resources root rather than related to the current file. Share your project structure to see the exact path.

Comment: I have added the project structure to my problem description. I haven't the permission to send pictures. I'm just a junior learner, so I described it in words

Comment: It is the problem caused by other parts of my code. I have modified it.